# Did the XUL script tag change?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have an about dialog in an extension that does not display properly in Firefox 43. I'm developing (at the moment) with the `xpinstall.signatures.required` option disabled (so I can test without having to jump through the signing hoop). When my dialog's XUL contains a `script` tag, the dialog fails to render. If I take that tag out, it renders just fine. The JavaScript within the attached tag appears to have no effect; even if it's empty, the dialog fails to render.

Did the `script` tag change recently? Are there new rules on loading scripts from a XUL window? My other dialog seems to work just fine, and I can't see anything glaringly wrong. Here's my XUL markup for the script tag:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://googlebarlite/content/about.js"/>
```

This tag lives within a `<dialog>` element in my XUL. If I visit the URL given in the `src` attribute, I can see the file just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**: I just realized that I have `application/x-javascript` as the type, but changing it to `application/javascript` doesn't change anything.

**Edit 2**: Here are the relevant lines from my chrome manifest ([full file](https://github.com/jgbishop/googlebarlite/blob/master/chrome.manifest)):

```
content googlebarlite chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://googlebarlite/content/googlebarlite.xul
```

And here's my folder structure:

```
root
+-- chrome/
    +-- content/
        about.js
        about.xul
        ...
    +-- locale/
    +-- skin/classic
+-- components/
+-- defaults/preferences/
+-- modules/
chrome.manifest
install.rdf
```

Comment: Have you registered `googlebarlite` content scheme? Is the path correct? Show your `chrome.manifest` and folder structure.

Comment: Does the `<script>` tag immediately follow the `<dialog>` tag?  If not, try moving it.  I know this is an old problem with `<prefwindow>` tags.

Comment: Yes, the script tag follows the dialog tag immediately.